# Power in a wind turbine

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, power, boundary-conditions

An wind turbine starts turning  by a wind speed of $v_b$ and it stops turning (rated wind speed, to prevent overloading) by a wind speed of $v_g$. By wind speeds between $v_b<v<v_g$, the power is given by:

$$P(t)=\frac{\rho}{2}\cdot C_p\cdot A\cdot\left(v^3-v_b^3\right)\tag1$$

For [wind turbine engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_gradient#Wind_turbines), a polynomial variation in wind speed with height can be defined relative to wind measured at a reference height of 10 meters as:

$$v=v_{10}\cdot\left(\frac{h}{h_{10}}\right)^\alpha\tag2$$

Where $v_{10}$ is the wind speed at $h=10$, $h_{10}=10$ meter and $\alpha$ is the Hellmann exponent.

Now, in order to find an average of those functions, I used integration:

- $$\overline{P}_v=\frac{1}{v_2-v_1}\int_{v_1}^{v_2}\frac{\rho}{2}\cdot C_p\cdot A\cdot\left(v^3-v_b^3\right)\space\text{d}v\tag3$$
- I substituted equation $(2)$ into equation $(1)$:
  $$\overline{P}_h=\frac{1}{h_2-h_1}\int_{h_1}^{h_2}\frac{\rho}{2}\cdot C_p\cdot A\cdot\left(\left(v_{10}\cdot\left(\frac{h}{h_{10}}\right)^\alpha\right)^3-v_b^3\right)\space\text{d}h\tag4$$

I used: the Betz-limit $C_p\le\frac{16}{27}$, $0<\alpha<1$, $\rho\approx1.274792307$, $A=\pi\cdot r_w^2$, $0<r_w<\frac{85}{2}$, $v_1=0$, $h_1=0$ and got the following boundaries:

- $$0<\overline{P}_v\le\frac{7225}{16}\cdot\frac{\rho}{2}\cdot\frac{16}{27}\cdot\pi\cdot v_2^3\tag5$$
- $$0<\overline{P}_h<\frac{289}{640}\cdot\frac{\rho}{2}\cdot\frac{16}{27}\cdot\pi\cdot v_{10}^3\cdot h_2^3\tag6$$

> Question: what are resonable values for $v_2$, $v_{10}$ and $h_2$?

Comment: The _solar-wind_ tag does not refer to green energy or wind energy.  It is referring to the supersonic flow of plasma from the sun.

Comment: @honeste_vivere how does that answer the question....?

Comment: It does not and that was not the point of my comment.  I was trying to help _dfrt_ to get better answers by using proper tags, thus gaining the attention of the proper audience.  The _solar-wind_ tag is irrelevant for this question so it should not be used as a tag here (I will edit it shortly).